# Tree structured database schema for Product categories

Tags: sql, database-design, relational-database

I am creating a data base for an eCommerce website but i am having trouble with data base schema for products categories which is some what like a tree structure.

A **vendor** can belong to one or more Department and **Department** can have one or more Categories and **Categories** can have one or more **Sub Categories**. Similarly sub categories can have its on child so forth...

A **product** should be mapped to a Vendor (if department is unknown) or a Department (if category is unknown) or Sub Category  so forth..

What would be the best way of doing this kind of complex relationship database.

Comment: what does "best" mean? Easiest to store, or fastest to query?

Comment: I mean fastest to query to get complete hierarchy structure possibley in xml format @StephaniePage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey you can do this in single table.

```
ID  PARENT_ID   NAME
------------------------------
1   0           vendor1
2   0           vendor2
3   1           department11
4   1           department12
5   2           department21    
6   3           category11
7   6           subcategory11
```

From above you can understand the whole...

Comment: That's a very simple solution for this problem.. How can i query it to give the tree structure in xml (MS SQL). It would be great if you could provide me the query..

Comment: Is this the best way of achiving the hierarch table structure or is there any better way of doing it. The saving part is easy in this structure but while retriving we need to write multiple queries for example to know the vendor of subcategory11 we need to find it by querieng each level on top.

Comment: Query can be relevant to this...
`create table YOUR_TABLE (id int(20) primary key, parent_id int(20) references YOUR_TABLE(id), name varchar2(100));`

And yes, this is most favorite structure in cases of tree kind of db structures.

Answer (score 3):

I spent days working on this issue.

Scenario:

Selling Ropes in : Accessories, Automotive > Accessories, Marine > Accessories

- Some ropes are only sold in Marine > Accessories
- Some ropes are only sold in Accessories (top menu item)
- Some ropes are sold in all 3
- In general, any item needs to be listed in any number of branches, and each branch needs to be any possible depth.  (This platform only allows 3, but designing for future)

**Collections** is how a certain store platform allows one to organize items.
Their fields are limited and only the Tags field seems to be available for custom information.  This is a comma delimited field of discrete terms in their system.

Here are the Collection ~~ criteria definition combinations for my scenario:

- Accessories ~~ tags = "Accessories"
- Automotive > Accessories ~~ tags = "Automotive > Accessories"
- Marine > Accessories ~~ tags = "Marine > Accessories"

I have a Category table with 3 categories:

```
Category_ID | Category_Text
 1             Accessories
 2             Automotive
 3             Marine
```

I sell 2 ropes: an **Automotive Tow-Rope** and a **General Purpose Nylon Rope**

Product table:

```
Product_ID | Product_Title
 1            Automotive Tow-Rope 
 2            General Purpose Nylon Rope
```

My data feed comes with a Category field with all the branches pipe-delimited.

```
..., Title, Category, ...
..., "Automotive Tow-Rope",  "Automotive > Accessories", ...
..., "General Purpose Nylon Rope", "Accessories | Automotive > Accessories | Marine > Accessories", ...
```

I split the Category fields into a relationship table like this Product_Category_Relationship data :

```
Product_ID | Branch | Level | Category_ID  (Showing text for clarity)
 1            1        1       2           (Automotive
 1            1        2       1                       + Accessories)
 2            1        1       1           (Accessories)
 2            2        1       2           (Automotive 
 2            2        2       1                       + Accessories)
 2            3        1       3           (Marine
 2            3        2       1                       + Accessories)
```

This way I can see the multiple branches, the depth of each and all the category paths.

I am using SQL Server locally to manipulate files at this point.  I finally got this query working to put it all together in a non-normalized way.

```
*** TO DO: JOIN CATEGORY TABLE FOR ACTUAL TEXT VS CAT_ID LIKE EXAMPLE ***
SELECT prod_id,  STRING_AGG (branchpath,' | ') AS allpaths
FROM
    (SELECT prod_id, branch,  STRING_AGG (cat_id,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY depth) AS branchpath
    FROM prod_cat_rel
    GROUP BY prod_id, branch) t
GROUP BY prod_id
```

The **STRING_AGG** function was the final life saver.  I saw discussions about similar functions on other platforms too, so this isn't a SQL Server only solution.

I tried lots of ways to get the data into a logical and flexible arrangement, and know that some will argue for other hierarchical structures, but this works for me.

Soon, I'll finish my new store and link it from my site: C'mon 's GO! (cmonsgo.com)

I hope this helps someone else.
Adam

Answer (score 3):

This is a recurring question. There are two common ways of storing hierarchies in pure SQL databases (some have hierarchical extensions which make it easier).

The first is the solution @ketan suggests. The challenge with this model is that it can be hard to find the full set of children - native SQL doesn't do recursion, so "find all children for Vendor x" can be hard.

The alternative was [suggested by Joe Celko](http://www.ibase.ru/files/articles/programming/dbmstrees/sqltrees.html) and is often referred to as "nested set". The example on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) is simple:

```
Node        Left    Right
Clothing    1   22
Men's       2   9
Women's     10  21
Suits       3   8
Slacks      4   5
Jackets     6   7
Dresses     11  16
Skirts      17  18
Blouses     19  20
Ball Gowns  12  13
Sun Dresses 14  15
```

To find all children for a given parent is easy:

```
SELECT Child.Node, Child.Left, Child.Right
FROM Tree as Parent, Tree as Child
WHERE
    Child.Left BETWEEN Parent.Left AND Parent.Right
    AND Parent.Left = 1  -- Given Parent Node Left Index
```